# How to multiply a list in a particular position of an array in two loops?

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, loops, matrix

I have a list K_interior like this:

```
#Initial matrices 
K_Interior = [8, 5, 9, 2]
Nx = 4
Ny = 4
N = Nx*Ny #of unknowns
M = np.zeros((N,N)) #N rows, N columns
B = np.zeros((N,1)) # N rows, 1 column
```

Then, I create two loops to make an array for M:

```
for i in range (1, Nx-1):
  for j in range (2,Ny):
    for k in K_Interior:
        n = i+(j-1)*(Nx) # convert ij grid point to the nth grid point
        M [n,n] = -4*k #main diogonal
        M [n,n-1] = 1*k # off diagonal to the left
        M [n,n+1] = 1*k # off diagonal to the right
        M [n, n-Nx] = 1*k #far off diagonal to the left
        M [n, n+Nx] = 1*k #far off diagonal to the right
        B [n] = 0
```

In this case, I just want to multiply one by one element of K_Interior list into each position of M (M[n,n]) that I set up . But, the problem is that M[n,n] have 4 positions, the first position multiplies by the 4 values from the K_Interior list, the second position do the same thing until final position. It's not what I want. I have no idea how to deal with that. Looking forward to you help.

This is the output of my code:
[image]

This is the output that I want to get:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example input, correct output, and the output you are getting? Also, to confirm, do you want `M` to be a `16x16` matrix?

Comment: Yep, I want the 16x16 matrix. I did edit my post to add more information from your question. Thanks for you response.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following what you want to do exactly, or how the values are being calculated, but one issue I am noticing is that you are reassigning each index, as opposed to manipulating it. This leads to only the last `k` value (in this case `2`)  being used to perform the calculations. So instead of `M [n,n] = -4*k`, I'm assuming you want to do something like `M [n,n] += -4*k`, where `-4*k` is being added `M[n,n]` (or /, -, *, depending on what you want to do). If multiplying og, mar dividinybe add a `if M[n,n] == 0` check so you don't always get `0`.

Comment: Thank you. But it's still not work to me. So I think maybe I am gonna use the other way, such as replace random values (a database I did prepare before) to the position of matrix that I want.